Lead/Lag statistical test in Python
I have two series of data, one showing positioning data and one showing price data. Generically the format is similar to the below:
Price:



Date
EUR
JPY
NOK
SEK




Date
price
price
price
price


Date
price
price
price
price



Positioning:



Date
EUR
JPY
NOK
SEK




Date
positioning
positioning
positioning
positioning


Date
positioning
positioning
positioning
positioning



what i have done so far is the below, but i'm not sure how to interpret these results or if there are better tests to show whether the positioning data leads the price data
for currency in currencies:
    print(f'\nGranger Causality Test for {currency}:')
    test_result = grangercausalitytests(pd.concat([positioning_data[currency], price_data[currency]], axis=1).dropna(), maxlag=4)


For the granger causality, check the p-values and determine if the null hypothesis( no lead lag effect) is rejected or not.
I would try to make both time series statationary and see more metrics like:

Correlation with lags

Transfer Entropy

Levy Area (Paper)


Each metric has its own assumptions, but they will give you enough to see if there exists a lead lag effect besides granger causality.

"I would try to make both time series statationary ". Agreed. I would use the first difference of prices (i.e. the price changes), not the price level, as the dependent variable you are trying to forecast. Probably same for "positioning" although that may require further investigation, I am not sure how this variable is defined.
